# Why VS Code contains emphasized items but no error?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I'm writing a React project in VS code. I met this problem in VS code. In my project, this folder **shows Contains emphasized items** and I know it means there is an error in my files. But in the picture:

[image: vs code project],

I have checked all files but no error was found.  So this makes me feel confused.

I have searched this problem on google and found a similar GitHub issue. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/54960

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Committing once with git can be resolved.

Comment: This happens when you've deleted files from your folder structure and haven't yet added the event to a commit. VS Code sees the uncommitted change as an 'issue', which doesn't explain itself very well!

Comment: Not sure if this may help someone in the future, but irrespective of react or Angular or any project, i faced this with angular. The way i was able to get rid of the red marker is by manually renaming the files and restoring it back. i did removed few files that were in git but haven't committed the new version. But trying with renaming the files and updating the references (for angular component refs) on all the files removed the red error like mark but not the comment when you hover that folder

Comment: The comment from @Slakinov is the key here and may be worth a separate (and accepted) answer

Comment: It does seem to happen because of uncommitted changes.

Comment: Happens when stupid mac creates `.DS_Store` files.

Answer (score 521):

Use the command, CTRL+SHIFT+P on windows or COMMAND+SHIFT+P on mac, then search "Developer: reload window", click on it, your vs will reload.

Unlike in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61699971/) earlier answer, I did not have to reset the cache.

Comment: This answer is more correct. When I open a sample application, it would not be right to git commit to fix a bug.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Seems like there is a keyboard shortcut for that (cmd-R) it wouldn't work though - only clicking the command from the dropdown would for for me.

Comment: How do we avoid this in the future?

Comment: Interesting.  I pressed F1 (same menu as pressing CTRL + Shift + P) and selected "TypeScript: Restart TS Server", but even that didn't fix the issue.  Only reloading the VSCode window solved the problem.

Comment: You are a lifesaver! I've spent so much time trying to figure out how to fix it before seeing your solution!

Answer (score 19):

1. Run `react-native start --reset-cache`
2. Reload VS with the command ***Ctrl + shift + p*** and searching **Developer: Reload Window**

Answer (score 14):

Just to know I was in an Angular project, using Windows, WSL, I created a service and after that I renamed it, when I committed the changes, I noticed this red mark.

I just pressed
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and then typed: `Developer: Reload Window`. It will just reload the entire project and the mark will disappear.

Comment: It's worked for metronic vue demo 3 project. After few minutes again not working.

Comment: Worked for a react project as well, and also for a simple node express server.

Comment: weird, that worked, but I have no idea why it changed color in the first place. Thank you.  Anyone care to explain what is going on?

Answer (score 8):

I saw this message after moving a file from one folder to another, renaming and committing everything to git.

The Visual Studio "Problems" window showed an issue with the "deleted" file. Somehow VS had left a window open for the original location of the file and in it's tab the file was labeled as "deleted". Closing that tab in VS got rid of the "Contains emphasized items"

Answer (score 6):

### This happens when you've deleted some files/folders from project and haven't yet added the event to a commit.

There is multiple solutions

**Option 1:** Close the VS code and open it again

**Option 2:** Commit your code chages in git(if you are using)

**Option 3:** Reload the VS code - *Use the command, `CTRL+SHIFT+P` on windows or `COMMAND+SHIFT+P` on mac, then search "Developer: reload window", click on it*

Answer (score 5):

When I was working on a angular application in the Visual Studio Code editor, I observed this. And resolved it by simply restarting VSCode.

Comment: Great. It works.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue.

Committing multiple times from within the VS Code did not help.

However, once I added the files and committed from the shell, everything fell in place.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this when I working on a Rails application using **Visual Studio Code** editor.

I used an underscore for a directory name, that is instead of `staticpages`, I named the directory `static_pages`.

However, committing the code change using the below commands fixed it:

```
git add .
git commit -m "commit message"
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the already deleted files were opened in the VS code. Closing those files resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is an edge case but I am putting it here just in case it helps someone in the future...

I had accidentally done a `git add .` before I had fully set up my `.gitignore` file, so it had staged a couple folders with hundreds of files (mostly the entire Electron `out` folder) that I definitely didn't want in the repo.

This is the procedure I went thru to clean up my staged files:

- updated .gitignore so that when I reverted the add I could be sure that GIT was ignoring the right files and folders (which worked, hundreds to 7, the moment I did the `git reset`)
- `git reset -f`
- noting that the correct files were now in line to be staged, I did:

  - `git add .`
  - `git commit -m "message"`
  - `git push`

When I returned to the regular file list, I noticed that `node_modules` was showing the "emphasized items" indicator. So just to make sure that I had actually gotten everything committed and such I tweaked .gitignore again (added `node_modules/**` just in case lol), did another commit, and still had the issue. Nothing helped, and like I said, it was confusing because the indicated files were under node_modules and it was in the ignore list.

So I hit cmd-p and ran `Developer: Reload Window`. It turned out out all I had to do was reload the window and the emphasized items went away entirely. Simple fix, confusing problem.

Apparently adding, reverting, then adding a subset of my directories confused vs code and it just needed to reload the window.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, pushing to git didn't solve the problem. I simply closed all files, cancelled my dev server and restarted VS Code. The emphasizing was gone.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64441805/) answer, I also had to commit after closing.

Answer (score 1):

git add .
git commit -m "your commit description"

If this not helps, after commit restart the VS CODE

Comment: This was it for me! I would prefer VS Code not care what's in my git tree though... seems pretty odd.

Answer (score 1):

Select this tab from toolbar - **View -> Problems**  or  `Ctrl + Shift + M` and on bottom Terminal you will see whats problem is it.

Answer (score 1):

For me it's because of the folder contains the `.DS_Store` file generated by my mac.

Comment: VS Code thinks there are pending changes in Git because of `.DS_Store` files in the folders. Solution: add `.DS_Store` to your `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because there are pending changes to be saved in git, so to solve this problem, open a command terminal and go to the folder where your project is located, execute the following commands

```
git add .
git commit -m "your commit description"
```

In my case it works with this.

Comment: Hello! While those commands may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

VSCode using React. Changed a folder name in the src folder. Would not pass compilation after changing names of components. Committed to git. Restarted the app with npm start. All is well.

Answer (score 0):

You may have hidden files. My Explorer was not listing hidden files in those directories. Hidden files on Linux begin with a . (for example, `.hidden.txt`)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, had copied files from a folder into another folder. git commit as suggested solved the issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

commit the changes, if still, the error is there, reopen the vscode

Answer (score 0):

answers mostly amazing. if your problem still doesn't recover after tried `Developer: Reload Window` and committing again, maybe you open a folder in vscode that inside your current folder. if your project folder has a folder that contains second .git folder, delete the second one (in inside folder). then try;

```
git add <folder_name>
git commit -m "your_msg"
```

i hope it works for someone

Answer (score 0):

I just had same issue and was resolved using `ctrl+shift+P`and searched for 'Developer:reload windows'. It got the issue resolved for me when I was planning of creating a new project to replace that. Hopping this helps! This issue occurred after refactoring my project files; Renaming, deleting and relocating of files and folders I mean. Looking at why this happened,I got this;beccause those folders and files wasn't yet committed and upon changes the editor couldn't identify it so it see's it an issue.
I am using <#Flutter>

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may be encountering a similar issue, but is using **Perforce**, and for whom the Developer: Reload Window command doesn't work, the thing that worked for me was to revert the whole folder. I was seeing the red dot  even though no files were showing an error, and no files were checked out. Doing a revert on the entire folder made the red dot go away.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is not about code errors or editor bugs, but only a temporary advice if you started to write some codes (without errors), but it is still not completed, and you save the document.

Example: Usually, when I need to write a JS functions or a CSS class name that requires well-organized names and structures, before I write the codes or properties themselves, I write empty structures like:

```js
function createSomething(){};
function editSomething(){};
function deleteSomething(){};
```

Or:

```css
.class-name-a{}
.class-name-b{}
.class-name-c{}
```

So, after writing a good order of codes with good functions names or class names, I finally start to fill each function or CSS class, and when I save the final file, the message "*contains emphasized items*" will be gone.

Answer (score -1):

uninstall any extension if you have installed in vs code.It will be solved.

Comment: Developers sometimes rely heavily on extensions, so recommending that they uninstall ALL extensions just because they some questionably emphasized files may not be the best advice. Maybe you could expand upon your troubleshooting here with some steps, or less consequential actions like DISABLING extensions.