# How do I turn off "Contains emphasized items" in Visual Studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

### I need to figure out how to turn off emphasized items in Visual Studio Code

This might sound like a strange requirement, but in my workflow vscode functions as less an IDE than a cross-platform ViM-esque frontend with lots of remote development tools built-in.

Due to this use case, I don't need or want the linting features to show up in the file browser. How might I accomplish this?

### Attempts to solve the problem

I've run out of search terms here and cannot find an answer.

1. Searches including terms in this question's title yielded little
2. SO-specific search queries also yielded little

   - This seems to be somewhat related, at least as a representation of the "feature" I'm referencing: [VS code containes emphasized items but no error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59366833/vs-code-containes-emphasized-items-but-no-error)
3. VSCode "preferences" do not appear to show what I'm looking for, likely an issue with me not searching for the right variable name.

In my experience with VSCode it has been wonderfully customize-able, so I'm guessing there's a setting somewhere ready to be modified to accomplish this. Any help much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My use case was a bit different: after viewing some files in a git submodule those files became linted, and errors and warnings cluttered up my VS Code Explorer file browser window on files I had no intention of ever handling. I basically wanted a way to clear out those lint warnings, and found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66467995/45978). The solution is to reload the window:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> on Windows/Linux, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> on Mac -- then select "`Developer: Reload Window`"

One by-product of reloading the window is that it clears out those unwanted warnings (at least until the next time I visit the file). It also has the effect of clearing out warnings on files that I would normally want to see, of course, but chances are I'll be visiting those files again soon, so it's fine. Not a perfect solution, but it works for me and my use-case; hopefully it can help others.

Comment: Nice workaround and thanks for sharing! I am going to accept this until someone finds a more permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to turn it off, but I had this on multiple folders and I fixed it by renaming the folder to a random name, then naming it back to the name it was before and the error would go away.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this issuse then uninstall extention then CtrlShiftP on Windows/Linux, ⌘ShiftP on Mac -- then select "Developer: Reload Window" then type developer: relode page this issuse automatically resovle
i have this issuse then i uninstall extension then this issuse resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to permanently prevent this by adding the files to the .gitignore file. It seems that this happens in a cloned repository when you add new files.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Which files did you add to accomplish this? I'm not sure this could be a solution, as most devs should want source checked-in to git.

Answer (score 0):

i took linted folder and cut/paste it other place, made readme file to main folder and placed moved folder back to main folder. worked for me several times now. i just wonder is there solution for not have to do this anymore cause i have this problem mainly every week

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).